# How to give the output of craft( character - region awareness for text detection ) to crnn

Tags: image-processing, pytorch, object-detection, image-recognition, faster-rcnn

I am doing text detection and recognition. I have used Craft(character-Region Awareness for text detection)https://github.com/clovaai/CRAFT-pytorch. it gave me an output of the image with a bounding box and a text file with numbers. I want to feed the output to CRNN https://github.com/bgshih/crnn . but I need ROI of text image to make CRNN work.how to connect craft and CRNN

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to give a cropped image to CRNN network to recognize character.

Simple method is as follow:

1. Give an image to the `CRAFT_pytorch`
2. Crop & save the image by bounding box result that output from `CRAFT_pytorch`
3. Give an cropped imagee to the `CRNN` as an input

If you call two function `CRAFT_pytorch` and `CRNN` at once, you can skip saving cropped image in Phase 2.

Comment: thanks, but my problem is how to crop and save the image from the output coordinates of CRAFT_pytorch so that I can use it as input for CRNN

Comment: what is output from CRAFT_pytorch. please let me know more clearly what you have and you have to do.